# simple map in python with function

Tags: python

just trying to do simple map and  include into map a player location using function, but player do not appear (map is empty)

Here are my code. Please help to solve. Thanks

```
import random

CELLS = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0),
         (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1),
         (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 2),
         (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3),
         (0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4)]

def get_locations():

    return random.sample(CELLS, 1)

player = get_locations()

def draw_map(player):

    print(" _" * 5)
    tile = "|{}"


    for cell in CELLS:
        x, y = cell

        if x < 4:
            line_end = ""
            if cell == player:
                output = tile.format("X")
            else:
                output = tile.format("_")
        else:
            line_end = "\n"
            if cell == player:
                output = tile.format("X|")
            else:
                output = tile.format("_|")
        print(output, end=line_end)


draw_map(player)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `random.choice(CELLS)`, not `random.sample(CELLS,1)`

[`random.choice(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) returns one random element out `seq`:

```
(1, 3)
```

[`random.sample(seq, 1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) returns one sublist of `seq` with one random element:

```
[(1, 3)]
```

With this small change, your program outputs :

```
 _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|X|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|
```